# Problem displaying information in Picker element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display items in an array inside of a Picker element. I am having trouble with displaying the information. I think this is because I am loading the information from Firebase inside a promise and react-native is rendering the Picker element before the information is loaded. I am not sure of how to get around this however.

This is where I call the information from Firebase:

```
loadProjects = (currUser) => {
        let projectRef = firebase.firestore().collection("Projects");

        let userLoc = "Users/" + currUser + "/Projects";
        let userRef = firebase.firestore().collection(userLoc);

        //Gets every single document in the Users 'Projects' collection and adds it to an array in the state.
        userRef.get().then((documentSnapshot) => {
            documentSnapshot.forEach((document) => {
                this.state.projectsArr.push(document.id);
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        });
    };
```

and I call it here just after the render method:

```
render(){             
        const currUser = this.props.navigation.getParam('currentUser', 'NO-USER');
        this.loadProjects(currUser);
```

And here is my Picker element:

```
<Picker
                selectedValue = {this.state.selectedProject}
                onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({selectedProject : itemValue})}
                >                    
                    {
                        this.state.projectsArr.map((item, index) => {
                            return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={index}/>);
                        })
                    }
                </Picker>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you need to specific your problem

Comment: @CuongTranDuc Sorry I didn't clearly specific, the problem is that the data is loading into my array fine, but it is not rendering in the ```<Picker.Item/>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're setting state wrong way

```
 userRef.get().then((documentSnapshot) => {
      const newProjectsArr = []
      documentSnapshot.forEach((document) => {
         newProjectsArr .push(document.id);
      })
      this.setState({
        projectsArr: newProjectsArr 
     }}
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put it in the render, you can make multiple calls. If you need a single call, do not put it in the render.

If you receive the data well, you can use `componentDidmount()`

```js
componentDidmount() {
         const currUser = this.props.navigation.getParam('currentUser', 'NO-USER');
        this.loadProjects(currUser);
}
```

Comment: Although this did not fix the problem, it was still helpful. Thank you!